# Dismissive list view: When a widget in a list is dismissed, how do I remove a corresponding entry to an array

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently, I have a list view that allows items within the list view to be dismissable. I want each item within that list view to correspond to an element within another list that contains text. And when that widget in the listview is dismissed, then the corresponding element in the other list also gets deleted. Does anyone know hot

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is that if there is any common thing in both list that are related to each other such as id or any else say text in your case ,After dismissible widget get triggered iterate via the second list just check if there's any common based on the 1st list item, and delete the item rebuild the state. Maybe adding some code might be better but so far this is the best way you can do. let me know if it work.